# The parameter app_id is required on Heroku omiAuth facebook Integration

Tags: configuration, devise, omniauth, facebook-login

I am getting the error "The parameter app_id is required" when I test my facebook login in my app. I guess it has to do with my configurations. Can you please check my configuration files and let me know if there is an error. I even set the app id and secret on heroku

```
heroku config:set FACEBOOK_APP_ID=133333333463066  
              FACEBOOK_SECRET=a7244e333333333a7a2bf9492a6089a0
```

Here is my omniauth initializer file : config/initializer/omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :facebook, ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"], ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"]
end
```

My devise initializer has the following line:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "FACEBOOK_APP_ID" , "FACEBOOK_SECRET"
```

What am I doing wrong ?

On localhost, I am getting this error instead:

```
{
 "error": {
  "message": "Missing client_id parameter.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 101
 }
```

}

I get this url when I try to login with facebook

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?  client_id=&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=email&state=223cbab26ab10640a2c1fe62508aecb94ffc2854721703de
```

As you can see, client id is empty in the URL.

Comment: On localhost, what happens when you direct put you fb parameters to `provider :facebook, "133333333463066", "a7244e333333333a7a2bf9492a6089a0"`, without ENV.

Comment: {
    "error": {
    "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the        Application configuration",
    "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
     }
      }

Comment: You should put correct silte url to you facebook app. For localhost it should be your local url.

Comment: Thanks again, now I don t get that facebook error, I only get login error even from the native login http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269771/nomethoderror-in-deviseregistrationscontrollercreate-undefined-method-encry